# Select node with same attribute name and but different values

Tags: xpath, mule, anypoint-studio

I have the below xml document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xf:Report_Data xmlns:xf="urn:com.xforce.report/Job_History">
   <xf:Report_Entry>
      <xf:EmployeeID>11111</xf:EmployeeID>
      <xf:Name xf:Descriptor="E Botha">
         <xf:ID xf:type="XID">1111111111111</xf:ID>
         <xf:ID xf:type="Employee_ID">22222</xf:ID>
      </xf:Name>
      <xf:RoleAssignedTo xf:Descriptor="Lena Johnson-Bey (51961)">
         <xf:ID xf:type="WID">222222222222</xf:ID>
         <xf:ID xf:type="Employee_ID">222222</xf:ID>
      </xf:RoleAssignedTo>
      <xf:RoleAssignedTo xf:Descriptor="Allison Sisk (21849)">
         <xf:ID xf:type="XID">333333333333</xf:ID>
         <xf:ID xf:type="Employee_ID">33333</xf:ID>
      </xf:RoleAssignedTo>
   </xf:Report_Entry>
</xf:Report_Data>
```

I need to extract the `Employee_ID` under the `xf:RoleAssignedTo` so I should get back `22222` and `33333`. I tried the below xpath and I am only getting the first `22222`:

```
/xf:Report_Data/xf:Report_Entry/xf:RoleAssignedTo/xf:ID[@xf:type='Employee_ID']
```

My goal is get back both 22222 and 33333. In some cases it could be more. I would greatly appreciate any help. I need to use xpath without resorting to xslt.

Comment: what tool are you using to query the XML document with this xpath? I ask because it returns both nodes for me using Python's `lxml` module.

Comment: I believe the problem isn't in the XPath itself, but the way you execute the XPath. Many XPath processor provides separate API for selecting only the first match and for selecting multiple nodes, such as, in .NET `SelectSingleNode()` vs `SelectNodes()`

Comment: We are using an Integration Tool Mule which is mostly configuration based but under the hood is Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following way to extract the value of all **Employee_ID** using XPATH3:-

```
 <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />

  <flow name="splitxml2Flow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/split" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-variable variableName="originalPayload" value="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" doc:name="Variable"/>
    <splitter expression="#[xpath3('//*:Report_Data/*:Report_Entry/*:RoleAssignedTo', message.payload, 'NODESET')]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
    <logger level="INFO" message="Employee_ID:- #[xpath3('*:ID[2]')]" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="true" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/> 
    <set-payload doc:name="Set Payload" value="Done"/>  
  </flow>
```

You will get all the value in **logger** as below:-

[image]

It will extract as many **Employee_ID** available in the XML